# CSS causing odd spacing at top of web page

Tags: css

On a test page I'm building I'm having this odd spacing appear at the top of the page and I am unsure of why this is.

As you can see from the CSS below, the body tag has the margin and padding set to 0.

Here's the test site URL to see what I mean by the spacing: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/testsite/index.html

**CSS:**

```
body{
background: #4f6ca6;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#header{
background:url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
height: 328px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #223c6d;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #254379;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #254379;
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #254379;       
}

#slider{
width: 960px;
height: 328px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="header">
 <div id="slider">
 <h1>Test Site</h1>
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<h1>` tag has `30px` of margin.

This is called an inspector:

[image]

Learn it, love it, then abuse it.

Comment: Like your answer. Will have to start taking notice of the inspect element feature in Chrome to help me spot in future :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's the top-margin of your `h1` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider doing an initial reset of most elements. This means more work for you initially, but gives you far greater control and significantly simplifies troubleshooting.

The [Meyer reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a very common starting point.